# the size of a string is the same size of a image after convert the image into string?

Tags: c#, string, azure

I have uploaded an image of size X and then I convert then into a string, I need to split the string in several strings of size Y. The size of the image and the size of the string is the same? I use javascript for the conversion and then in c# i need to split the string, so I can send this trough a service bus connection.

My problem is that service bus connection in azure only accepts messages of 256kb and my image size limit is 7MB. This code works for small images

I upload the image and convert it to string:

```
    function SaveDocuments() {
    showModalMessage('Please wait ...');
    setTimeout(function () { saveDetailstoServer() }, 1000);
}

function saveDetailstoServer() {

    var organization = $("#organization").val()
    var documentsToSave  = ""
    for (var i in documents) {
        //alert(documents[i].name);

         documentsToSave +=   documents[i].toString() + "||"

    }
    organization = organization.replace(/"/g, '└') + "||"
  //  userEmail = "";


    SendDetailsToServer(new Array(new Array("documentsToSave", documentsToSave), new Array("organization", organization), new Array("userEmail", userEmail)));

}

function SendDetailsToServer(parameters) {
    var url = baseUrl + "SaveDocuments";
    var parameterString = ArrayToJson(parameters);
    project_ajax(url, processResponse, null, "POST", parameterString);
}
```

In my c# code i receive this as a string and my intention is to send this trhough service bus, but the message size is to big when the image is bigger than 200 kb.

```
namespace OpenIdProviderRole.Services
{
    public class FEUserDocumentationManager : BaseManager
{

    public string SaveDocuments(string documentsToSave, string organization, string userEmail)
    {

        FEInterRoleCommunicator communicator = new FEInterRoleCommunicator();
        string result = communicator.SendCommand<Shared.DTOs.Parameters.SaveDocumentsParameters, string>("SaveDocuments",
               new Shared.DTOs.Parameters.SaveDocumentsParameters
               {
                   Documents = documentsToSave,
                   Organization = organization,
                   UserEmail = userEmail
               });
        return result;
    }
}

}
```

I want to split the documentsToSave parameters so the service bus accepts my message.

Comment: Dump image to storage and pass id through service bus? For you string problem you need to show some code as it is not clear what exactly you are trying to split - there is no canonical way to "convert image to string" - so hard to guess. Normally you'd split string with `string.substring` in language of your choice.

Comment: What @AlexeiLevenkov said; we need to see the code that actually converts the image into a string.

Comment: there you have, i use a simple .toString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split long string into collection of multiple shorte strings use [String.substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aka44szs(v=vs.100).aspx). Something like:

```
var slices = Enumerable.Range(0, longString.Length/ blockSize + 1)
   .Select(blockIndex => longString.Substring(
       startIndex: blockIndex * blockSize, 
       length: Math.Min(longString.Length - blockIndex * blockSize, blockSize)));
```

Note that approach with slicing of the string requires sending multiple messages to satisfy message size cap and hence properly merging them back on other side. Better approach would be to store larger data in blob storage (or similar storage for large objects) and pass blob ID instead of content.